# How do i convert chr to ord? - Python

Tags: python, chr, ord

in my python program i generate a list of numbers which looks like this:

```
gen1=(random.sample(range(33,126), 8))
            conv=(gen1[0:])
```

then that list is converted to chr like this:

```
chr="".join([chr(i) for i in conv])
```

the printed result for example would look like this:

```
`&+hs,DY
```

Now my question is, how do i convert it back to how it was in 'conv' later on in my program, the user enters the generated key and my program need to reverse engineer it back to calculate something, i tried this:

```
InPut=input("Please enter the key you used to encrypt the above text: ")
        ord_key="".join([ord for d in InPut])
```

but that doesnt work if there is numbers in the key that was generated earlier 
please help me

Comment: First off,  `conv=(gen1[0:])` is the same as gen1 so unless you want  copy of gen1 then just use gen1, don't use `chr` as a variable name, you need to `(str(ord(d))` in your list comp  but that is not going to give you the same output as conv or gen1, you need to just call `ord(d)` to match the output and forget join.

Comment: thanks i did all of that and i get "str objed is not callable" any ideas

Comment: Then you have also shadowed `str`, don't use builtin functions/types as variable names

Comment: what do you mean by Shadowed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not calling `ord` properly, this should do:

```
InPut=input("Please enter the key you used to encrypt the above text: ")
ord_key="".join(map(str,[ord(d) for d in InPut]))
```

if you want to reverse the stringfied `'&+hs,DY` just `map` chr to it:

```
reversed = map(chr, "`&+hs,DY")
```

If you are using python 3.x transform it to a list:

```
reversed = list(map(chr, "`&+hs,DY"))
```

Comment: that returns this: <map object at 0x02F354D0>

Comment: transform it to a list, I suppose you are using python 3.x then?

Comment: thanks for the help and yes im using 3.5.0 and running it in idle

Comment: how do i transform it?

Comment: You also cannot join ints

Comment: i got : an integer is required (got type str)

Comment: has anyone of you guys have skype? so you can help me i can show you my whole script? I thank you though for your help

Comment: or i can private message you it?